# Can flask rest api application can run on gunicorn alone?

Tags: python, flask, webserver, gunicorn, wsgi

I'm currently developing HTTP Rest API server using Flask. I don't have any static media, and all url are being served by @app.route pattern in Flask Framework. Can Flask run on Gunicorn alone with out webserver?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - gunicorn *is* a web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Flask - logic to respond to HTTP request
2. gunicorn - Helps manage concurrency for these HTTP requests, logging, worker timeouts
3. nginx - scalability and protection. If the load for your application is higher, Nginx would help for load balancing without crashing your Application Server, helps to serve static content if any

So if load for your application is less and no static content to serve, in my opinion, flask + gunicorn should be OK.